Composition of symbols of pseudo-differential operators
For $m \in \mathbb{R}$, denote the set $S^m$ to be the set of all $\sigma \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n)$ such that for any $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{N}^n$, there exists $C_{\alpha, \beta}> 0$ such that
\begin{equation*}
|(D_x^{\alpha}D_y^{\beta}\sigma)(x, y)| \leq C_{\alpha, \beta} (1 + \|y\|)^{m - |\beta|}
\end{equation*}
I am having a little bit of trouble trying to show the following:

If $\sigma_1 \in S^{m_1}$ and $\sigma_2 \in S^{m_2}$, then $\sigma_1\sigma_2 \in S^{m_1 + m_2}$.

However, I want to show that $\sigma_1\sigma_2 \in S^{m_1 + m_2}$, so I would have to fix $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{N}^n$, and find a $C_{\alpha_1, \beta_1} > 0$ such that
\begin{equation*}
|(D_x^{\alpha}D_y^{\beta}\sigma_1\sigma_2)(x, y)| \leq C_{\alpha, \beta} (1 + \|y\|)^{m_1 + m_2 - |\beta|}
\end{equation*}
I know that by definition above, because $\sigma_1 \in S^{m_1}$ for any $\alpha_1, \beta_1 \in \mathbb{N}^n$ there exists $C_{\alpha_1, \beta_1} > 0$ such that
\begin{equation*}
|(D_x^{\alpha_1}D_y^{\beta_1}\sigma_1)(x, y)| \leq C_{\alpha_1, \beta_1} (1 + \|y\|)^{m_1 - |\beta_1|}
\end{equation*}
and similarly, because $\sigma_2 \in S^{m_2}$, $\alpha_2, \beta_2 \in \mathbb{N}^n$ there exists $C_{\alpha_2, \beta_2} > 0$ such that
\begin{equation*}
|(D_x^{\alpha_2}D_y^{\beta_2}\sigma_2)(x, y)| \leq C_{\alpha_2, \beta_2} (1 + \|y\|)^{m_2 - |\beta_2|}
\end{equation*}
But using this information, I am not entirely sure how to proceed from here. Some help would be much appreciated.

What happens if you apply the Leibniz rule?

Observe that for $\delta \leq \beta$ it holds $|\beta-\delta| + |\delta| = |\beta|$. Then by Leibniz rule
$$\left|D_x^\alpha D_y^\beta(\sigma_1\sigma_2)(x,y)\right| = \left|\sum_{\gamma\leq \alpha}\sum_{\delta \leq \beta} {\alpha\choose\gamma} {\beta \choose \delta}D_x^\gamma D_y^\delta \sigma_1(x,y) D_x^{\alpha-\gamma}D_y^{\beta - \delta} \sigma_2(x,y)\right| \\
\leq \sum_{\gamma\leq \alpha}\sum_{\delta \leq \beta} {\alpha\choose\gamma} {\beta \choose \delta} \left|D_x^\gamma D_y^\delta \sigma_1(x,y)\right| \left|D_x^{\alpha-\gamma}D_y^{\beta - \delta} \sigma_2(x,y)\right| \\
\leq \sum_{\gamma\leq \alpha}\sum_{\delta \leq \beta} {\alpha\choose\gamma} {\beta \choose \delta} C^1_{\gamma,\delta}(1+||y||)^{m_1-|\delta|} C^2_{\alpha-\gamma,\beta-\delta}(1+||y||)^{m_2-|\beta-\delta|} \\
= \sum_{\gamma\leq \alpha}\sum_{\delta \leq \beta} {\alpha\choose\gamma} {\beta \choose \delta} C^1_{\gamma,\delta} C^2_{\alpha-\gamma,\beta-\delta}(1+||y||)^{m_1+m_2-(|\beta-\delta|+|\delta|)}
\\ = \left(\sum_{\gamma\leq \alpha}\sum_{\delta \leq \beta} {\alpha\choose\gamma} {\beta \choose \delta} C^1_{\gamma,\delta} C^2_{\alpha-\gamma,\beta-\delta}\right)(1+||y||)^{m_1+m_2-|\beta|} = C_{\alpha,\beta}(1+||y||)^{m_1+m_2-|\beta|},$$
where
$$C_{\alpha,\beta} := \sum_{\gamma\leq \alpha}\sum_{\delta \leq \beta} {\alpha\choose\gamma} {\beta \choose \delta} C^1_{\gamma,\delta} C^2_{\alpha-\gamma,\beta-\delta}.$$
Thus $\sigma_1\sigma_2 \in S^{m_1+m_2}$.
